# How to refresh data when we add an option to an tableau parameter?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Tableau report that has a parameter. I added a new calculation to the parameter. But when I try to refresh data on the report (upon clicking my new option in the parameter list) it doesn't refresh data in the report.

Comment: Where did you put the calculated field (that uses the parameter) on the workbook?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a parameter in order to filter data on your worksheet, then it must be part of a calculated field (that is then used as a filter) or used directly within a Top N filter as follows:

- [Using Parameters in Calculated Fields](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/help.htm#parameters_calculations.html)
- [Using Parameters in Filters](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/help.htm#parameters_filters.html)